# What is better in JavaScript Custom Events or normal Function calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In Js code if there are two js objects(One Handling a UI(example a Form) and other posting a request to a server.

What would be the better way to interact between these components using Custom Events or Normal Function call.

For Example.

```
  clickForm = function(){
      validateForm();
      $(document).trigger("submitForm",{"userData":userData});//Event submitForm listened by formManager submitForm method.
  }
```

OR

```
clickForm = function(){
     validateForm();
     formManager.submitForm(userData);
  }
```

`clickForm` method is part of the UI Component which is responsible for managing the UI interaction of the HTML Code.This function is usually called when a submit button is clicked.

`submitForm` method is part of the core Object whose responsibility is to make request to the server,parse the response and then send the result to the UI Component.

Which one of these two methods is a better way to interact. Any Suggestions?

Comment: I am not very familiar with javascript but I don't need that to ask: Better for what? For example, there maybe something that's great for performance but awful for code readability.

Comment: Just want to add that using the Event Model helps big time for code reuse and code sharing. You can hook into events and create custom listeners when you need to expand, whereas using normal function calls is more limited (but quicker because of the overhead associated with the Event Model). In some cases the performance overhead of using the Event Model is negligible vs function calls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Better" is a tricky concept. :-)

Using events couples the objects more loosely, which is usually considered a good thing, and allows for the possibility going forward of more than just the two objects collaborating (for instance, more than one subscriber to the event; and conversely an object could subscribe to the event on two sources).

The event mechanism will have more overhead, which doesn't matter in most cases (certainly not when submitting a form), but could in a small class of cases (something that happens thousands of times a second). Event mechanisms *can* be a bit trickier to read and debug, as well.

Comment: Yeah debugging can be a problem with events.Is there a way in which event can described where the debugging much easier.How the custom event based big application maintains a way where it is easy to detect which objects are listening to an event.

Comment: I would love to see some performance statistics on both methods; if anyone has a good site or reference that would be really helpful.

Comment: Events are great for plugins (see http://leafletjs.com/ for example). Downside is race-conditions, it's hard to control perfectly the order of things, which also makes for tricky debugging.

Comment: Event-Based Architecture: Getting Decoupled https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/event-based-architecture-getting-decoupled/